# Custom session handler in PHP 7 using mysql

Tags: php, session

I already have read all about Sessions in PHP on stackoverflow but it haven't help. I have session class that was working on PHP 5.X, and I haven't been programing since.
I have been started about month ago again with PHP, but my session handler is invalid.
Please, can you help me?

```
<?php
<?php

    /*
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
      `se_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `se_value` mediumblob,
      `se_expires` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ALTER TABLE `sessions`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`se_id`), ADD KEY `se_id` (`se_id`,`se_expires`);
     */

    define( "MAXLIFETIME", 86400 );
    define( "DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo" );
    define( "DB_USER", "root" );
    define( "DB_PASS", "whatever..." );

    final class MYSession{
        protected $_table_name = 'sessions';
        protected $_primary_key = 'se_id';
        protected $_where = array();
        protected $_order_by = 'se_id';

        protected $data = array( "se_id" => "",
                                 "se_value" => "",
                                 "se_expires" => ""
                               );

        public $se_id;
        public $se_id_old;
        public $db;
        private $sessionName;

        //public $maxlifetime = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime");
        public $maxlifetime;
        private $path;
        private $domain;
        private $secure;
        private $httponly;

        public function setParams(){
             ini_set( 'session.gc_probability', 1 ) ;
             ini_set( 'session.gc_divisor', 100 );
             ini_set( "session.use_only_cookies", TRUE );
             ini_set( "session.use_trans_sid", FALSE );
             ini_set( "session.use_only_cookies", "1" );
             ini_set( "session.entropy_file", "1" );
            }

        public function startSession( $sessionName, $maxlifetime = FALSE, $path = FALSE, $domain = FALSE, $secure = FALSE, $httponly = FALSE ){

             $this->setParams();

             if( $maxlifetime ){ $this->maxlifetime = $maxlifetime; }
             else{ $this->maxlifetime = 0; }

             if( $path ){ $this->path = $path; }
             else{ $this->path = "/"; }

             if( $domain ){ $this->domain = $domain; }
             else{ $this->domain = NULL; }

             if( $secure ){ $this->secure = $secure; }
             else{ $this->secure = isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] ); }

             if( $httponly ){ $this->httponly = $httponly; }
             else{ $this->httponly = TRUE; }

             $this->setSessionCookieData();

             $this->sessionName = $sessionName;

             session_name( $this->sessionName );

             session_set_save_handler(
                                      array( $this, "open" ),
                                      array( $this, "close" ),
                                      array( $this, "read" ),
                                      array( $this, "write" ),
                                      array( $this, "destroy" ),
                                      array( $this, "gc" )
                                     );
             session_start();
             session_regenerate_id( TRUE );
             $this->se_id = session_id();
             $this->gc( $this->maxlifetime );

             return $this->se_id;
            }


        public function setSessionCookieData(){      
             return session_set_cookie_params( $this->maxlifetime, $this->path, $this->domain, $this->secure, $this->httponly );
            }

        public function getSessionCookieData(){
             $sessionCookieDataArray = array();
             $sessionCookieDataArray = session_get_cookie_params( );
             return $sessionCookieDataArray;
            }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public function __destruct(){ session_write_close(); }

        public function newSessid(){ return $this->se_id; }

        public function oldSessid(){ return $this->se_id_old; }

        public function open( $path, $se_id ){
             try{
                 $this->db = new PDO( DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
                 $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE );
                 $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                }
             catch( PDOException $error ){ echo 'Error: '.$error->getMessage(); }
             return TRUE;
            }

        public function close(){
             $this->db = "";
             return TRUE;
            }

        public function read( $se_id ){
             $sql = "SELECT se_value FROM ". $this->_table_name. " WHERE se_id = :se_id";
             try{
                 $statement = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
                 $statement->bindValue( ":se_id", $se_id, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                 $statement->execute();
                 $result = $statement->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
                }
             catch( PDOException $error ){ die( "Unable to access to database read1" ); }

             if( !empty( $result[ "se_value" ] ) ){
                  $sql = "UPDATE ". $this->_table_name. " SET se_expires = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( UTC_TIMESTAMP() ) WHERE se_id = :se_id"; 
                  try{
                      $statement = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
                      $statement->bindValue( ":se_id", $se_id, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                      $statement->execute();
                     }
                  catch( PDOException $error ){ die( "Unable to access to database read2" ); }
                 }
             return $result[ "se_value" ];
        }

        public function write( $se_id, $se_val ){        
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->_table_name . " WHERE se_id = :se_id AND se_value = :se_val";

             try{
                 $statement = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
                 $statement->bindValue( ":se_id", $se_id, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                 $statement->bindValue( ":se_val", $se_val, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                 $statement->execute();

                 if( $statement->fetch() ){          
                    $sql= "UPDATE ". $this->_table_name. " SET se_value = :se_val, se_expires = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( UTC_TIMESTAMP()) WHERE se_id = :se_id";
                    $statement = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
                    $statement->bindValue( ":se_id", $se_id, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $statement->bindValue( ":se_val", $se_val, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $statement->execute();              
                   }               
                 else{
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO ". $this->_table_name. " ( se_id, se_value, se_expires ) VALUES( :se_id, :se_val, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( UTC_TIMESTAMP()) )";
                    $statement = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
                    $statement->bindValue( ":se_id", $se_id, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $statement->bindValue( ":se_val", $se_val, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $statement->execute();                              
                   }
                }
             catch( PDOException $error ){ die( "Unable to insert or update database" ); }
        }

        public function destroy( $se_id ){
             $sql = "DELETE FROM ". $this->_table_name. " WHERE se_id = :se_id";         
             try{
                 $statement = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
                 $statement->bindValue( ":se_id", $se_id, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                 $control_var= $statement->execute();
                }
             catch( PDOException $error ){ die( "Unable to destroy data in database" ); }

             $this->gc( $this->maxlifetime );        
             return ( $control_var );
        }

        public function gc( $maxlifetime ){
             $sql = "DELETE FROM ". $this->_table_name. " WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP( UTC_TIMESTAMP() ) - se_expires > :maxlifetime";
             try{
                 $statement = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
                 $statement->bindValue( ":maxlifetime", $this->maxlifetime, PDO::PARAM_INT );
                 $control_var = $statement->execute();
                }
             catch( PDOException $error ){ die( "Unable to select from database_" ); }
             return ( $control_var );
            }

        public function regenerateId( ){
             $this->gc( $this->maxlifetime );

             $old_sessid = $this->se_id;
             session_regenerate_id( TRUE );
             $new_sessid = session_id();

             $sql = "UPDATE ". $this->_table_name. " SET se_id = :new_sessid WHERE se_id = :old_sessid";
             try{
                 $statement = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
                 $statement->bindValue( ":new_sessid", $new_sessid, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                 $statement->bindValue( ":old_sessid", $old_sessid, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                 $control_var = $statement->execute();

                 $this->se_id = $new_sessid;
                 $this->se_id_old = $old_sessid;
                }
             catch( PDOException $error ){ die( "Unable to select from database_REGID" ); }
             return $new_sessid;
            }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public function destroySession(){
             if( ini_get( "session.use_cookies" ) ){
                 $params = session_get_cookie_params();
                 setcookie( $this->sessionName, '',
                            time() - 42000,
                            $params["path"],
                            $params["domain"],
                            $params["secure"],
                            $params["httponly"]
                           );
                }
             $_SESSION[ $this->sessionName ] = array();
             unset( $_SESSION[ $this->sessionName ] );
             session_unset( $this->sessionName );
             session_destroy();
            }

        public function generateSessionName( $brojZnakova ){
             return substr( $this->generateId(), 0, $brojZnakova );
            }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public function generateId(){ //private
            $salt                   = 'x7^!bo3p,.$$!$6[&Q.#,//@i"%[X';
            $random_number          = mt_rand( 0, mt_getrandmax() );
            $ip_address_fragment    = md5( substr( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, 5 ) );
            $timestamp              = md5( microtime( TRUE ).time() );

            $hash_data = $random_number . $ip_address_fragment . $salt . $timestamp;
            $hash = hash( 'sha256', $hash_data ); //'sha256', 'haval160,4', 'md5' 

            return trim( $hash );
           }

    }

    $newSession = new MYSession();
    $newSession->setParams();
    $newSession->startSession( 'newSession' );

?>
```

Comment: You can't have two `<?php` at the beginning? Is that a copying error?

Comment: You need to provide more details about the problem than just "is invalid".

Comment: Maybe look to implement `SessionHandlerInterface`?  Then use the newer prototype: `session_set_save_handler ( object $sessionhandler [, bool $register_shutdown = TRUE ] ) : bool`

Comment: Two <?php is my mistake. That is not a problem.

Comment: Simply, I can't start a session.